# Microsoft Edge does not render SVG External Content

Tags: svg, microsoft-edge

I'm getting an issue when trying to use external svg content on Edge. I found serveral sites that says Edge support SVG External Content since EdgeHTML version 13, but I do not know.

My current version of EdgeHTML is: 13.10583, and [here](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/11/16/introducing-edgehtml-13-our-first-platform-update-for-microsoft-edge/) is where I read about support.

[This](https://plnkr.co/edit/9KHRx173YiifYffvjGIB) is what I'm trying to visualize.

```html
<svg>
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="map.svg#back"></use>
</svg>
```

My results on chrome:
[image]

My Results on Edge:
[image]

P.D I know this is not working for older version or IE, so I'm using svg4everybody lib, it does not work with Edge 13.

Comment: In the screenshot you provided, your xlink ns uri is wrong (you wrote `.../2000/...` instead of `.../1999/...`)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, anyways that's not the problem. I was just playing around.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `<img>` and then embed it instead of using xlink.
There are already some code in here.
I recently created a tool for myself that works nice on all browsers
https://github.com/IskrenStanislavov/svg-embed